# Biblatex-mla gives me a \smartcite error

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

Using:
`Biblatex 1.4a`
`Biblatex-mla 0.95`

Biblatex set up as follows:
`\usepackage[style=mla,autocite=footnote,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

When I run XeLaTeX (`XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4`), I get an error on my first run:
`! Package biblatex Error: Command '\smartcite' undefined.`

The .tex file compiles fine using `biblatex-chicago`, and my polyglossia and csquotes declarations are fine:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
```

I'm not using `\smartcite` anywhere in my document (only `\autocite`), so I'm wondering if it's a compatibility issue.
Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a compatibility issue, since `\smartcite`, which was introduced in biblatex 1.3, internally uses `\autocite`, as the following code from `biblatex.def` shows:

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
```

As a temporary workaround, you could redefine this to:

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\footcite}{\footcites}
```

This should work with biblatex-mla 0.95 (though I have not tested it).

Comment: That's great to know, thanks. I was hoping it would be a compatibility issue, and not a gremlin.

Comment: The work around works great but it seems the error still happens when I use `\autocites` (the multi-cite version). I'm highly confused as to why, since the last argument of `DeclareAutoCiteCommand` seems to declare the multi version.

Comment: @iKs: domwass's solution works with `\autocites`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31192/