# biblatex-mla: Changing cited bibliographic entries in the footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I use this code to get cited refrences to be displayed in the footnotes:

```
\usepackage[style=mla,style=verbose]{biblatex}
```

When a reference material is first cited, it displays the full bibliographic content. This is fine for me. But when the same reference material is cited again (second or multiple times), it displays the following: `footnote number as super-script, author's surname, title, page number`. My Supervisor has told me to print only the following with materials cited second or multiple times: `footnote number as super-script, author's surname, page number`. I should omit the book title. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You cannot use two styles at the same time. I think that you just use the verbose style if you load biblatex as shown. If I did not get it wrong, the biblatex-mla style does not show the first citation in full. Do you really need MLA style, or which requirements for the style do you have?

Comment: If I use only `style=mla`, it will not show references in footnotes. So using `style=verbose` shows references in footnotes and also in `Works Cited` list at the end.

Comment: if I use `\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}`, the document compiles fine, but rerences only appear at the end of the paper. But if I use `\usepackage[style=mla,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}`, it shows up errors during compilation. And the document never gets compiled.

Comment: The errors are due to the fact that `biblatex-mla` is based upon an outdated `biblatex`, and thus lacks the CiteCommand `\smartcite`. But even with this command, `biblatex-mla` will give only short citations in footnotes, no full references. If this is not what you want, you should consider using (and modifying) one of the `verbose` styles.

Comment: @domwass Could you convert your comments to an answer? They seem to explain what is up here pretty clearly.

Comment: @JosephWright: done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use two styles at the same time. I think that you just use the `verbose` style if you load `biblatex` as shown. If I did not get it wrong, the `biblatex-mla` style does not show the first citation in full.

Apart from that, `biblatex-mla` is based upon an outdated `biblatex`, and thus lacks the CiteCommand `\smartcite`. But even with this command, `biblatex-mla` will give only short citations in footnotes, no full references. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journaltitle = {Zeitschrift},
  date = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19-75}
}
@book{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  location = {Buch am Wald},
  date = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=mla,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:mla}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\autocite{article,book}

\cite{article,book}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```