# How can I create bibliography in MLA format with BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mla-style

I know how to create a bibliography of the MLA style manually:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{Poz}
    Pozrikidis, C. \emph{Boundary Integral And Singularity Methods For Linearized Viscous Flow}. Cambridge [England] : Cambridge University Press, 1992. Print.

\end{thebibliography}
```

The link about BibTeX gives the following description:

> If a document references this handbook, the bibliographic information may be formatted in different ways depending on which citation style (APA, MLA, Chicago etc.) is employed. The way LaTeX deals with this is by specifying \cite commands and the desired bibliography style in the LaTeX document.

It does not mention *how* can the bibliographic information be formatted in different style.

**Question:**
How can I create the bibliography automatically with [BibTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) with the same [MLA style](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/06/)? (Window Vista, MiKTeX, WinEdt 6.0)

[**EDITED:** ]Are there other ways to create the bibliography in MLA style in LaTeX?

Comment: There is MLA style for `biblatex`. It isn't complete though and hasn't been updated for quite some time. I actually contacted its author some time and got no response.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `biblatex-mla` package seems to do a good job with basic MLA style citations and bibliographies. Here is an example of how to use it.  You need to run `latex biber latex latex` to get everything to look right.

**Update (July, 2016)**
It seems that development of `biblatex-mla` has resumed. Using the latest version on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla?lang=en) this example compiles properly.  I would *strongly* recommend you update your TeX distribution to TL 2016 instead of manually installing the package, since there have been many changes to both `biblatex` and `biber` which will also need to be updated, so manual updating will likely lead to package dependency conflicts.

Various previous problems with `biblatex-mla` may have been fixed with this new version, so the warning on the previous version of this answer may not apply.

**Previous Warning**

As the comments have mentioned, and also this question: [biblatex-mla sometimes \autocite[prenote][pg]{key} is not printing the author's name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45593/2693) there seem to be significant problems with `biblatex-mla` which hasn't been updated for some time.  It may need to be used with `biblatex` version 1.0.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{mla-test-bib.bib}


@article{Kavanaugh1976,
    Author = {Kavanaugh, Robert D.},
    Journal = {Child Development},
    Month = {Sep},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {885-887},
    Title = {On the Synonymity of `more' and `less': Comments on a Methodology},
    Volume = {47},
    Year = {1976}}


@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

\end{filecontents} % This is the end of the sample bibliography

\addbibresource{mla-test-bib.bib} % you would use your own bib file here
\begin{document}
This is a citation. \autocite{Saussure1995}. Another citation \autocite{Kavanaugh1976}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you need footnote citations, use the package option `autocite=footnote` and add the following code to your preamble (based on the solution posted here: [Biblatex-mla gives me a \smartcite error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15715/2693)).

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\footcite}{\footcites}
```

If you need to change the title of the bibliography to something other than "Works Cited", add the following code to your preamble:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
    \section*{Bibliography}}   %use \chapter* if the bibliography will be a chapter
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What's `biber' here?

Comment: @Jack: See Alan's great answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/4012.

Comment: Can I change "Works Cited" into "Bibliography"?

Comment: @Jack I've added some code to change the "Works Cited".

Comment: @AlanMunn `biblatex-mla` seems to have [some issues](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45593/4483) with pre- and postnotes.

Comment: @Audrey I can't reproduce that error with this sample document.

Comment: @AlanMunn Try again with recurrent citations: `This is a citation. \autocite[e.g.][27--45]{Saussure1995}. Another citation \autocite[e.g.][27--45]{Saussure1995}`. There's also a spacing issue with postnotes.

Comment: @Audrey Still seems to work. (The spacing issues are annoying.) I don't use MLA myself, though, so I certainly haven't encountered all of its problems.

Comment: @AlanMunn Odd. With your preamble and that document body, I don't get the author name in the second citation.

Comment: @Audrey Oops. You're right, of course. I was just paying attention to the page number part.  I wonder if that's by design? (I don't know MLA specs very well.) I guess biblatex-mla really isn't to be recommended any more.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'd guess some form of ibidem abbreviation should be set. I am far too lazy to sort out the style's `cbx` file to tell for sure. Until biblatex-mla gets updated, it should probably only be used with biblatex 1.0.

Comment: Is biblatex 1.0 available anywhere?

Comment: @AlanMunn Here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-1.0/

Comment: @AlanMunn So I had a look. The absent author *is* by design. Spacing issues still stand. Sorry for dragging your question into this.

Comment: This did not work for me. Running this code in texmaker on EL Capitan throws `Missing \begin{document}` on line 7

Comment: @kilojoules Unfortunately the `biblatex-mla` package has not been updated in some time, and there have been significant changes to `biblatex` along the way. Even when this answer was written it was in jeopardy (as stated in the answer; see the comments).  It's not clear at this point what a good solution is.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am only a n00b but I posted a new question about this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320702/cite-mla-from-bib

Comment: @kilojoules The error you got was because of a misplaced comment line after the `\begin{filecontents}`  (my error). Please copy the edited version of the code and try it again with an up-to-date TeX distribution.

Answer (score 5):

I found this package online called MLA13 that does everything for you. I used it in quite a few of my papers already. The thing that's good about it is that it uses your .bib files and formats everything according to MLA standards.

The website for this is:

Documentation: https://github.com/jackson13info/mla13/blob/master/Documentation.pdf

Github: https://github.com/jackson13info/mla13

This package allows you to format your entire document and to create the works cited in mla format you simply type `\makeworkscited` and it will format the entire page using your bibtex file.

Comment: It looks like this package no longer works. Neither command `\usepackage{mla13}` or (per the README) `\usepackage{mla13.sty}` work.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the [`mla` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mla-paper?lang=en) helps with this.

From that page:

> To use the bibliography feature,
>
> 1. Use  \begin{workscited} to start the bibliography.  There is no need to declare a new page or even type "Works Cited" at the top of the page.
> 2. Use   \bibent  before each entry.
> 3. Put   \end{workscited} at the end.
> 4. There is no reason to use BiBTeX or any of the other bibliography packages

And an example of a Works Cited entry from the page:

> \bibent
>
> author's last name, first name.  ``Paper Title."  \textit{Book Title}.  Date of publication.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of having a single database of bibliographic data, connecting citations with the bibliography,  and also doesn't help with actually formatting either the bibliography or the citations.