# biblatex-mla sometimes \autocite[prenote][pg]{key} is not printing the author's name

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

### Context

I am working with Emacs 23, Auctex, Texlive 2011,
biblatex-mla.  My operative system is Linux Mint Lisa.

I am writing my dissertation. I use a dissertation.cls and a
master document. This is part of the preamble in the master
document:

```
\usepackage[portuguese, spanish, american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\bibliography{thesis}

\newenvironment{mlaquote}
{\list{}{
 \leftmargin 1 in
 \itemindent 0in
 \topsep 0in
 \partopsep 0in
}\item\relax}
{\endlist}
```

### Problem

Frequently  I need to include this prenote: (qtd. in). Sometimes the following
command works just fine:

```
\autocite[Quijano qtd. in][ 23] {Caetano1986}
```

the result is: (Quijano qtd. in Caetano and Rilla 23).

But in this case:

```
\autocite[Quijano qtd. in][44-5]{Caetano1986}.
```

the result is: (Quijano qtd. in 44-5)

I wonder why the autor is missing in the second case.

I think that my preamble is working fine because I am able to
work with articles, books, incollections, thesis, chapters,
etc, without a problem. Everything looks fine in the PDF except
for some references with a prenote.

I was thinking that I had some compatibility issue between Auctex
and Biblatex and I try to fix it with this post:
[Customising emacs to use biblatex-biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/customising-emacs-to-use-biblatex-biber-instead-of-bibtex)
But at the end, I could not fix this issue.

Here is my bib entry:

```
@BOOK{Caetano1986, 
title = {El joven Quijano (1900-1933): Izquierda nacional y conciencia cr\'itica}, 
publisher = {Ediciones de la Banda Oriental}, 
year = {1986}, 
author = {Gerardo Caetano and {Jos\'e Pedro} Rilla}, 
location = {Montevideo}, 
owner = {alfredo}, 
shorttitle = {Joven}, 
timestamp = {2011.04.24} 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you provided a bit more information about the bib entry `Caetano1986`, as there's possibly something in that entry that confuses `\autocite`. Barring that, I'd try to enclose the string `44-5` in double-quotes (`"`) or replace it with `44f.` (It's either a reference to a page number or a range of page numbers, right?)

Comment: Just as a comment: personally I like 44--45 better than 44-5, but if there are format requirements, you have got to follow those, of course.

Comment: @ad2012 The author is intentionally missing in the second citation because it's the same as the last citation. You can see this from the `cite:idem` bibmacro in `mla.cbx`. There are spacing issues with postnotes. Those might get resolved if you roll back to an earlier version of biblatex. (biblatex-mla hasn't been updated since December 2010.)

Comment: Hi Audrey. I will check how to install biblatex 1.0

Comment: I am following Audrey´s directions. But I don't know how to roll back biblatex. For this reason, I post this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45676/if-i-have-tex-live-2011-how-to-install-a-previous-version-of-biblatex-1-0

Answer (score 5):

The absent author names are by design in biblatex-mla. This can get problematic if the recurrent citations are separated by a lot of text. To avoid omission of names entirely, you can redefine the `cite:ibid` bibliography macro. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:reset}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:mla:noibid}}

\begin{document}
\autocite[e.g.][27--45]{companion}
\autocite[e.g.][27--45]{companion}
\autocite[e.g.][27--45]{bertram}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the document compiled with biblatex 1.0.

[image]

For reference here's (unedited) biblatex-mla output with biblatex 1.7 and hyperref:

[image]

Use of both biblatex 1.0 and hyperref appears to resolve spacing issues with postnotes, but you'll have to omit any extraneous whitespace in your pre- and postnotes. For example `\autocite[Quijano qtd. in][ 23]{Caetano1986}` should be changed to `\autocite[Quijano qtd. in][23]{Caetano1986}`.

Comment: Audrey thank you so much. I tried to install biblatex 1.0 yesterday and after several tries and mistakes I had to reinstall TeX Live again. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ad2012 Sorry you ran into so much trouble. The `cite:ibid` fix works with biblatex 1.7. There might be a way to fix the spacing issues through style edits, but I don't have time to look into it.

Comment: Right now everything is fixed. I install biblatex (0.9a) using the TeX Live Manager. What I did was to change the repository's address back to TeX Live 2009. The manager resolve all the dependencies and everything looks in order. The spacing issues are fixed to. – ad2012 just now

Comment: I posted how I fix this problem here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45676/if-i-have-tex-live-2011-how-to-install-a-previous-version-of-biblatex-1-0

Comment: Audrey's solution works well, but Biblatex-mla provides an additional solution built into it to avoid unclear references across paragraphs. The package option `mancitepar` will reset the ibid and idem trackers at every paragraph to try to avoid too much space between citations. Would it be helpful, too, to avoid ibid situations when there's a `prenote` defined?

Comment: @JamesClawson Not sure - I'm not familiar with the MLA style. Good to hear that you've returned to development, though. I can imagine it must be tough for style authors to keep up with the biblatex releases.

Comment: Falling behind a release or two made it that much harder to return to things, but your bugfixes elsewhere have been a good help to get me back on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your usage of biblatex, use `\usepackage[style=mla,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex}`.