# Force Biblatex to Print Author in Citation

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biblatex-mla sometimes \autocite[prenote][pg]{key} is not printing the author’s name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45593/biblatex-mla-sometimes-autociteprenotepgkey-is-not-printing-the-authors)

I am writing a literary essay with Biblatex as my works cited engine (running biber).

I only have one source (one book) that I cite/reference numerous times throughout my essay. However, the author last name is only printed on the first citation; on subsequent citations only the page number is printed.

The desired behaviour for this essay would be to have the author printed on every citation, even though it is the same work each time. How could this be achieved?

Thank you for taking the time to read my (hopefully simple) question!

**EDIT** (I should've realized a MWE would've helped):

Here's a similar LaTeX file to mine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\defbibheading{customworkscited}[\refname]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}\doublespacing}

\begin{document}

First paragraph, interesting fact. \autocite[\pno~10]{ex00}

Second paragraph, other interesting fact by same author. \autocite[\pno~20]{ex00}

\clearpage
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=customworkscited]

\end{document}
```

Here's a similar Bib(la)TeX file to mine:

```
@BOOK{ex00,
  author = {Example Guy},
  title = {Example Book},
  year = {2000},
  publisher = {Oxford Press},
  location = {New York},
  owner = {Me},
  quality = {1},
  timestamp = {2013.01.20}
}
```

For the first paragraph, I get:

> First paragraph, interesting fact. (Guy 10)

For the second, I get:

> Second paragraph, other interesting fact by same author. ( 20)

The desired appearance of the citation in the second paragraph would be the same as that in the first, namely:

> (Guy 20)

Hope this clears up any confusion!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added a MWE, sorry for not doing so initially.