# Force Author Name on Subsequent Instances of Biblatex Autocites

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, mla-style, biblatex-mla

I am trying to use MLA-style in-text citations using Biblatex+Biber and am running into an issue with the formatting of subsequent in-text citations of the same source.

My desired output is:

`"First quote" (Author 53). [Continue writing]. "Second quote" (Same Author 72)`

But if I use `\autocites[pg#]{source}` two or more times with the same source, all subsequent instances are outputted only as `(pg#)`.

Is there any way for me to override this and make Biblatex output both the author and page number every time?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature of the style. It can be turned off as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45593/35864.

Comment: @moewe Thank you! Works perfectly!