# MLA Style Citations and Bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, mla-style

I'm a complete beginner at LaTeX but would now like to write a mathematical article with `MLA` style referencing. The set of references I'm using are for this article only and nothing else, so I don't need to be able to use the same references for several documents. Also, I have no experience with `bibtex` or `biblatex`, nor have I ever used the citation system that comes with LaTeX. What is the most direct way to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44921/31323) and as you have never used `biblatex` before, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/31323) might also help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It looks like you might benefit from a general introduction to LaTeX. I suggest you start with [The not so Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/) by Tobi Oetiker and then work through [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/index.html) by Nicola Talbot. (Use the entries and arrows in the right hand column to move through the tutorial.) You may think at first that it's tedious to go through a couple of tutorials, but you'll find that the pay-off to such an up-front investment will be great.

Comment: [A very brief introduction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) to citation systems with LaTeX.