# Cite MLA from .bib

Tags: bibliographies, mla-style

How can I produce an MLA citation from a .bib file? e.g., if I have a `refs.bib` . bib file in my project folder:

```
@article{10.1371/journal.pone.0141854,
    author = {Ross, Cody T.},
    journal = {PLoS ONE},
    publisher = {Public Library of Science},
    title = {A Multi-Level Bayesian Analysis of Racial Bias in Police Shootings at the County-Level in the United States, 2011â2014},
    year = {2015},
    month = {11},
    volume = {10},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0141854},
    pages = {1-34},
}
```

How can I site this in MLA format in a document? Here is my best attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I define white privilege as common societal benefits people identified as white receive which are beyond the benefits typically experienced by people who would not be identified as white. These benefits are apparent in our present society in a number of forms, from excessive police shootings \cite{ross_multi-level_2015} to subtler benefit disparities like how the vast majority of the time I talk to a person of authority they are the same skin color as me. 
\bibliography{refs}
\bibliographystyle{mla}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "MLA" stands for "Modern Language Assocition", right? Does the MLA recommend the APA (6th ed.) formatting conventions?

Comment: @mico No, the MLA is its own beast. Very different from APA.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Many thanks for providing this clarification. :-)

Comment: @kilojoules I'll update the answer to [How can I create bibliography in MLA format with BibTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44888) and then we will close this as a duplicate (I think.)